# PyCharm CE does not recognize .pyx files

Tags: python, pycharm, cython, pyx

PyCharm Community Edition (CE) does not recognize few Cython files as shown in the picture below (with PyCharm red mark under the file name).
Could you please advise me on what can I do ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyCharm Community Edition does not support Cython. You should get PyCharm Professional Edition to get that [feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cython.html).

Comment: You could perhaps try Visual Studio Code, but I find myself better off with PyCharm.